# how to support all characters(ı,ö,ü,ç,ğ,.. e.g) in listview after parsing Xml with SAXparser?

Tags: android, parsing, listview, character, saxparser

ı parse the xml tags with SAXparser.Then put on the listview..But these characters arent show.Instead of them showing question mark(?). How can ı figured out this problem?

Comment: Make sure that the inputstream you use for the parser is coding the bytes in UTF-8

Comment: Maybe you could edit and post the code where you get the String in the  SaxParser

Comment: how ı am supposed to edit to string??

Comment: I mean, to edit your post and paste the code where you get the String in your SaxParser